# How to pass an image URL to a function via onclick without repeating the same URL twice

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to pass the “image1.jpeg” source URL to the “toggleImage” function via onclick without having to input the same URL again. Is there a way to reference the “image1.jpeg” URL in the onclick? I experimented with the “this” keyword but couldn’t get it to work.

As is, it works fine but I don’t like redundancy of using the same URL twice. Any suggestions?

```
<img src="/image1.jpeg" alt="Alt Name" id="Test" onclick="toggleImage('/image1.jpeg','/image2.jpeg','Test' )">
```

```
function toggleImage(src1, src2,imgID) {

    if (document.getElementById(imgID).src == src2)
    {
        document.getElementById(imgID).src = src1;
    }
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById(imgID).src = src2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up something like the below:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" onclick="switchImage(event)" data-second="image2.jpeg">
```

```
function switchImage(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    let target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    
    let originalSrc = target.src;
    let secondImage = target.dataset.second;
    
    target.src = secondImage;
    target.dataset.second = originalSrc;
}
```

Comment: Using “data-second” seems like a good idea, but in your function where do I specify the “id=test”? Each pair of images on the page will have a unique ID.

Comment: You don't have to do that. Using the event handler here and it automatically knows what image was clicked, no need to target it with an ID.

Comment: It absolutely works! Though I’m still trying to understand *how* it works with my beginner’s level of javascript. Can you explain that to me?

Comment: This page helped me understand the first part: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31544108/what-is-window-event-in-javascript#31544288

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using ternary operator:

```js
function toggleImage(src1, src2, imgID) {
  const img = document.getElementById(imgID);
  const url = 'https://example.com'
  const newImg = img.src === url + src2 ? src1 : src2;
  img.src = url + newImg;
}
```

Comment: Looks interesting but my image URL can’t be a const since it changes for each pair of images.

Comment: It is `const` only in function scope. Feel free to change `const` to `var`.

Comment: Thanks but the main issue is that I don’t want any URLs inside of the function, that’s why I’m passing them to the function from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass 'this' to your changeImage function, which will reference the HTML-Element which triggered the click event in your DOM.

This should work:

```html
<img src="/image1.jpeg" alt="Alt Name" id="Test" onclick="changeImage(this,'/image2.jpeg','Test' )">
```

```js
function changeImage(SenderElement, src2,imgID) {
    // Here you can access the "src" attribute of your HTML-Element via 
    // SenderElement.src ex:

    console.log(SenderElement.src);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37q42tzb/2/

Comment: I used ‘this’ as you suggested but in the function when I try to put SenderElement.src in place of src1 it’s not working for me. Am I missing something?